# Передача файла через form, создание на этот файл ссылки и передача его в скрипт python Flask

Tags: python, flask

Нужно взять аудио файл и обработать его функцией python, также сохранить в текстовом файле для последующей обработки, все это происходит через фреймворк Flask.
Я создал форму и сделал обработчик нажатия на кнопку. Но я не могу передать это файл в функцию которая запускается при нажатии на обработчик.

Вопрос 1: Как лучше работать с файлами напрямую или сохраняя их в БД(папку)?

Вопрос 2: Если файл сохраняется как к его можно взять для дальнейшей обработки функцией?

Подскажите пожалуйста и накидайте код для того. чтобы я разобрался. В интернете информации найти не могу.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, flash, send_from_directory
from test_module import test
from module_audio_to_text import wav_to_text

app = Flask(__name__) # Создаем приложение из класса Flask
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'dsafyvnjdhtDNf9454Dfws' #Секретный ключ для работы с формой

@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
@app.route("/index", methods=["POST", "GET"]) # Создаем ссылку на страничку
def index():  # Описываем работу страницы (Приложения)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form['username'] != '':
            flash("Файл загружен")
        else:
            flash("Ошибка загрузки файла")

    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/my-link/') # Обработчик нажатия на клавишу
def my_link():
    res = wav_to_text()
    return render_template("index.html", message=res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам просто нужно сохранить файл внутри фласка, то используйте:

```py
if request.form['file'] != '':
    f = open('w', 'путь к файлу куда хочешь сохранить')
    f.write(request.form['file'])
    f.close()
```

Пж лайкни ответ если поможет

Comment: Параметры `open` идут в другом порядке - сначала имя файла, а потом режим открытия

Comment: Ты прав, я совсем забыл...

Comment: Как, мне его потом выбрать, чтобы поместить его в скрипт.

Comment: Открываешь, читаешь, передаешь в качестве аргумента, и уже в html достаешь